# Loosing the result in table made from postgres DATABASE

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I am trying to make a simple project of DB to my school. I am occuring strange kind of error. When I am getting the external name from HTML input to select query, I always lose 1 result. I am trying to make DELETE from my PHP interface but I can only do it when there are more than 1 same records. I don't have any ideas how to fix it.

look into code

I tried to make integer which gets value from HTML name and then includes it in the query but nothing happened

Into PHP:

```
echo" <form name='display' action='delete.php' method='POST' >
<li>ID Dłużnika:</li>
<li><input type='number' name='indeks' /></li>
<li><input type='submit' name='submit' /></li>
<li><input type='submit' name='new' /></li>
</form>
";
$db = pg_connect("host=localhost  dbname=dluznicy user=pdacko password=elowariat");
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT imie,nazwisko,indeks,miejsce_zamieszkania,kwota_zadluzenia FROM spis_dluznikow where indeks = $_POST[indeks] ");

$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

.
.
.
 while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Expected is error at

```
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT imie,nazwisko,indeks,miejsce_zamieszkania,kwota_zadluzenia FROM spis_dluznikow where indeks = $_POST[indeks] ");
```

Where I lose 1 record and can only see where there are more than 1 with the same index(ID)

Comment: You really should read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: It's simple project which needes only to include delete insert and update, i don't care about rest

Comment: You really should read the link I posted. You'll start to care, when someone uses the vulnerability in your program and destroys you database...